# WooCommerce single product content restructure

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 2.1x.
I want a reposition of the WooCommerce tabs in product detail.

I already made child templates. I only cannot find the place where I actually change the pattern of items within the content-single-product.php

I want to display the tab after the image, before the product summary part. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the default woocommerce `add_action` for the tabs :

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );`

Now add a new `add_action` to hook in the tabs where you want. in this case you want it to appear before summary part and after image, add this :

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 30 );`

See that we have added a priority of `30` as Product images are hooked at priority `20` and we want tabs to appear after the product Images.

You should also consider the answer provided by -Aibrean as that will help you in future.

Comment: yeah. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

The actions list is on

```
woocommerce / includes / wc-template-hooks.php
```

The best way to reorder/change pattern is through removing action/filter and adding in your own functions file. That way you can keep it intact even if Woo updates.

[WooCommerce Product Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268011/woocommerce-product-template/24297432#24297432) This might be helpful as I've shown how to deconstruct and re-order from one summary area to another.