# woocommerce - add extra coupon area

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce to build a custom webshop.

On the checkout page, i'd like my coupon area to be on the bottom of the page, instead of at the top(which is the default).

I'ts being called with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
```

In that action, there's the login and the coupon. I want the login to stay up there and the coupon to get to the bottom. But I dont know where or how to seperate them. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of 10 to something "higher" like 20 or 30 (a lower number indicates higher priority). See [WordPress Coxed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) on actions, "Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action."

You can override in your functions file (recommended).

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 30 );
```

Alternatively, you can move the 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' to another area (like right now it's set as 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form') by changing the action.

I've also got a reply for a scenario relating to moving elements in a WooCommerce theme here: [WooCommerce Product Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268011/woocommerce-product-template/24297432#24297432)

Comment: In the answer in your link, you say to find the template hooks in: 'woocommerce / includes / wc-template-hooks.php'. Only I can't find every one of them there. this one for example: "woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details"

Comment: And also, i've moved the coupon area, but now it doesn't have the harmonica effect anymore. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: It's hard to know without looking at a live example and showing the anticipated end result. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/ this has a listing of all hooks and what template pages they are attached to in order to be loaded in.